# How to get values inside the method

Tags: c#

I get the SNMP oid value to string variable. it was apc-ups battery remaining time.but variable value like "0d 2h 22m" but i want it only minute.when i debug the program i can see the value i want inside the method [code debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZth2.png) 
this is my code

```
     string host = "ipaddress";
     string community = "private";

     string[] requestOid;
     Dictionary<Oid,AsnType> result;
     requestOid = new string[] { ".1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.2.2.3.0" };

     SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp(host,community);

     result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver2, requestOid);

     string res = result.Values.ToString();


     foreach (KeyValuePair<Oid, AsnType> kvp in result)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(kvp.Value.ToString());            
     }
```

Comment: The value, according to your screenshot, is in _milliseconds_. So just convert that to minutes.

Comment: I can't get the millisecond to another variable. That's the problem

Comment: What do you mean with you can't "get it to another variable"? Do you mean you don't know how to read the millisecond value?

Comment: Yes, i cant read millisecond value

Comment: Finally i found way                                                                                                           `[long RemMin; TimeTicks tim = new TimeTicks();
            AsnType ast = result.ElementAt(1).Value;
            tim.Set(ast);
            RemMin = tim.Milliseconds / 60000;]`

Answer (score -1):

You can convert Time unit like hour to minute\seconds\milliseconds [Time conversion](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-milliseconds-seconds-minutes)

Comment: OP's issue is not the conversion, it's getting the millisecond value in the first place.

Comment: yes #DarkDust is right.I want get the milisecond value to varible